# MP Chart not displaying inside Layout :Android

Tags: android, charts, linechart

I'm trying to put a MP Line Chart into my relative layout. but the issue is when I run it on my phone or emulator there is no content(the chart is not displaying)I've tried to fix this but no luck.please help me in this,I really need your help.Thank you.

in this app im trying to fake a set of points so that it will make the graph look real.

below is my Main activity and it's xml

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ChartHelper mChart;
    LineChart chart;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            chart = findViewById(R.id.graph);
            mChart = new ChartHelper(chart);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    mChart.addEntry(Float.valueOf(26));
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    mChart.addEntry(Float.valueOf(27));
                }
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                mChart.addEntry(Float.valueOf(25));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

below is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutmain"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/graph"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and below is my ChartHelper class

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.listener.OnChartValueSelectedListener;

public class ChartHelper implements OnChartValueSelectedListener {

    private LineChart mChart;

    public ChartHelper(LineChart chart) {
        mChart = chart;
        mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);

        // no description text
        mChart.setNoDataText("You need to provide data for the chart.");

        // enable touch gestures
        mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);

        // enable scaling and dragging
        mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
        mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

        // if disabled, scaling can be done on x- and y-axis separately
        mChart.setPinchZoom(true);

        // set an alternative background color
        mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mChart.setBorderColor(Color.rgb(67,164,34));


        LineData data = new LineData();
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        // add empty data
        mChart.setData(data);

        // get the legend (only possible after setting data)
        Legend l = mChart.getLegend();

        // modify the legend ...
        // l.setPosition(LegendPosition.LEFT_OF_CHART);
        l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);
        l.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
        l.setTextColor(Color.rgb(67, 164, 34));

        XAxis xl = mChart.getXAxis();
        xl.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
        xl.setTextColor(Color.rgb(67, 164, 34));
        xl.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xl.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
        xl.setEnabled(true);

        YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
        leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.rgb(67, 164, 34));

        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);

        YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
        rightAxis.setEnabled(false);

    }

    public void setChart(LineChart chart){ this.mChart = chart; }

    public void addEntry(float value) {

        LineData data = mChart.getData();

        if (data != null){

            ILineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
            // set.addEntry(...); // can be called as well

            if (set == null) {
                set = createSet();
                data.addDataSet(set);
            }

            data.addEntry(new Entry(set.getEntryCount(),value),0);
            Log.w("anjing", set.getEntryForIndex(set.getEntryCount()-1).toString());

            data.notifyDataChanged();

            // let the chart know it's data has changed
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // limit the number of visible entries
            mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10);
            // mChart.setVisibleYRange(30, AxisDependency.LEFT);

            // move to the latest entry
            mChart.moveViewTo(set.getEntryCount()-1, data.getYMax(), YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

            // this automatically refreshes the chart (calls invalidate())
            // mChart.moveViewTo(data.getXValCount()-7, 55f,
            // AxisDependency.LEFT);
        }
    }

    private LineDataSet createSet() {
        LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(null, "Data");
        set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        set.setColor(Color.rgb(67, 164, 34));
        //set.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
        set.setLineWidth(2f);
        //set.setCircleRadius(4f);
        set.setFillAlpha(65);
        set.setFillColor(Color.rgb(67, 164, 34));
        set.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(67, 164, 34));
        set.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(67, 164, 34));
        set.setValueTextSize(9f);
        set.setDrawValues(false);
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
        Log.i("Entry selected", e.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(){
        Log.i("Nothing selected", "Nothing selected.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into your code I figured out that you were blocking the `Main Thread` by calling `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);` in the `onCreate()`. So, I put the blocking call in a new `Thread` so that it doesn't block the `Main Thread`. Please have a look at my following workaround,

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ChartHelper mChart;
    LineChart chart;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        chart = findViewById(R.id.graph);
        mChart = new ChartHelper(chart);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                            mChart.addEntry(Float.valueOf(26));
                        }
                        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                            mChart.addEntry(Float.valueOf(27));
                        }
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                        mChart.addEntry(Float.valueOf(25));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }

}
```

> After Above modification I found your code working and plotting graph.

[image]

Comment: This worked Thank you very much @Roaim you literally saved me.

Comment: It's my pleasure. Can you please read this, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem inside your for loop.
Try this is working.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            mChart.addEntry(i);
        }
```

Comment: the phone is literally a blank, i think its something wrong with ui

Comment: Also my API level that im using is 28 while the MP Chart version that i use is com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0

Comment: did you tried my code,because your code cause ui blocking,and MP chat version is fine.

Comment: yup. still the same blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

> chart.invalidate()

,  and remove TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1) its cause blocking the main UI thread try

```
  try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        chart = findViewById(R.id.graph);
        mChart = new ChartHelper(chart);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                mChart.addEntry(Float.valueOf(26));
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                mChart.addEntry(Float.valueOf(27));
            }
            mChart.addEntry(Float.valueOf(25));
        }
        chart.invalidate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It is a problem related to the UI

Comment: Does it throwing any exceptions because the above code working on my end

Comment: should i include dependencies in the pom.xml file. I saw a requirement but couldnt find that file,cus the project is not maven